# Pointing out correction in my name in the enrollment letter I received

Tags: management

I received an enrollment letter from a company, but it contains an error in the spelling of my name.

How can I politely point out that spelling mistake and ask for it to be corrected via email?

Answer (score 17):

I think you've answered your own question, you can just politely point out the issue in an email:

> Hello So-and-so,
>
> Thank you for submitting the enrollment letter! I am excited about joining your company. However, I was reviewing the letter just now and I noticed that my name is misspelled as *user105659* when it should be *SuperUser.* I wanted to point that out to ensure that you have my name correctly in your system.
>
> Thanks again and I'm looking forward to working together.
>
> Sincerely, SuperUser